# Converting Timestamp to Month without the 00:00:00

Tags: sql, presto, trino

I have a timestamp that looks like this:

2022-01-23 03:50:48

I want it to look like this:

2022-01-01

However, it currently looks like this:

2022-01-01 00:00:00

My SQL Logic:
`, DATE_TRUNC('month', DATE(timestamp))    as reporting_month`

Is there anyway I can make it look like just the month and the year?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`date_format`](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/datetime.html#date_format) to format date value:

```sql
select date_format(now(), '%Y-%m-%d')
```

| _col0 |
| --- |
| 2022-04-27 |

Or cast timestamp to date:

```
select date(now())
```